# Create a structure that contains a pointer to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, struct

I CAN NOT USE VECTORS FOR THE ASSIGNMENT

I have to create a structure that stores the following information: student name, id number, pointer to an array of test scores, average test score, letter grade.

The program should keep a list of test scores for a group of students. It should ask the user how many students are in the class and how many test scores there are.The number of test scores will be the same for every student. The program should dynamically allocate an array of structures. Each structures Tests member should point to a dynamically allocated array which will hold the test scores.
After the arrays have been dynamically allocated, the program should ask the user for the id number and all of the test scores for each student. The average score should be calculated and stored in the Average member of the structure. Display the student info.

I am having trouble when the user enters the test scores in the `inputScores` function. I can't figure out how to access the structure member right. Can you please look at my code and help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my structure:

```
struct Grade
{
    string name;
    int idNum;
    int* tests;
    double average;
    char grade;
};
```

Here are my functions:

```
//user enters number of students which is then used as the size of the dynamically allocated struct array
int inputStudents();
//user enters number of tests for each student which is then used as the size of the dynamically allocated array of test scores in the structure
int inputTests();                   
string inputName();                 
int inputID();  
//user inputs scores for each student. this is a function i'm struggling with               
int *inputScores(int *testScores, int numTests);        
double calcAvg(int *testScores, int numTests);          
char calcGrade(double);     
void display(Grade*, int);
```

Here is my main:

```
int main()
{
    Grade *studentList;
    int size = inputStudents();
    studentList = new Grade[size];      //dynamically create array of Grade struct

    int numTests = inputTests();        //number of test scores stored in numTests                      

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)                  //loop to store all student's info
    {
        studentList[i].name = inputName();
        studentList[i].idNum = inputID();
        studentList[i].tests = inputScores(studentList[i].tests, numTests, i);
        studentList[i].average = calcAvg(studentList[i].tests, numTests);
        studentList[i].grade = calcGrade(studentList[i].average);
    }

    display(studentList, size);

    delete[] studentList;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the function i am struggling with. Every time I reference `studentList` a different error appears. My program won't even compile and I'm pretty sure this function is the reason why. Here I pass the `tests` structure member, rather than the entire structure. I also pass the number of tests and the counter from the loop in `main` that tells us which student the user is entering the test scores for.

```
int *inputScores(int *studentList, int numTests, int count)         
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the test scores:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++)
    {
        studentList[count].tests = new int[numTests];       //my error says the studentList must have a class type
        cout << "Score " << (i + 1) << ": ";        
        cin >> studentList[count]->tests[i];                //my error says studentList must have a pointer type 
        cout << endl;
    }

    return studentList->tests;     //my error says studentList must have a point-to-class type

}
```

Comment: Hi Meagan, welcome to stack overflow. Please read [ask] and [example]. Right now your question has a lot of extra stuff in it that doesn't have to do with your problem. Can you cut your program down to an example that shows just the problem you're having, without all the extra stuff?

Comment: Also if you have any compiler errors or warnings, please include the exact text. If your code compiles, but doesn't function correctly, please give us a sample input that replicates the error, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Thanks that helps. You could get away with removing all the functions from your `main` except for `inputScores` since that's the only one you're having trouble with, but this is doable.

Comment: *I CAN NOT USE VECTORS FOR THE ASSIGNMENT* -- I really don't understand these restrictions in this day and age of C++ (vector has been part of C++ for over 20 years now).  It's not as if the program will automatically write itself if vectors are used.  You still need to come up with the logic of the program.

Comment: @Paul I took an assembly class in undergrad. By and far the most important thing I learned from the class was, "don't use assembly," but it still helped me understand what was going on under the hood of a "higher" level language like C++. Similarly, forcing students to to do their own memory management is good for teaching the CS concept. Maybe there's a better way. I'm not a CS guy.

Comment: @John Then have the student actually create a vector class (thus introduce the rule of 3, copy constructor, assignment op, destructor, etc.) instead of an assignment where they are throwing pointers around all over the place in an incoherent fashion.

Comment: @Paul I think that's a good solution.

Comment: @OP Just to let you know, the given code still has memory leaks, as `tests` is never deallocated. @John [here is a video on teaching C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk)

Comment: @Paul I'll have to put this on my watch list for later. 1 hour is too much for now. I'm already up way too late. Okay I lied I've been sucked into it.

Comment: thank you for all the help! I was finally able to get my code to work.

Comment: I think the *use a std::vector* misses the point. There is 30 years of code out there that uses `new` and `delete`. Unless we ensure the next generation of programmers has a firm grasp on handling memory management on their own, we are kinda shooting ourselves in the foot. (not to mention, how much more they appreciate the internal handling provided by `std::vector` later... Like @John and the assembly class...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to each student's test array to `inputScores()` but accessing it as a pointer to a student. You would have to change the `inputScores()` function as given below:

```
void inputScores(int *tests, int numTests, int count)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the test scores:\n";


    for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++)
    {
        cout << "Score " << (i + 1) << ": ";        
        cin >> tests[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Also, I made one more modification. Its always better if the caller function allocates memory and pass a reference to the array. So we need to call the inputScores() function as given below

```
studentList[i].tests = new int[numTests];
inputScores(studentList[i].tests, numTests, i);
```

This is the output I received:

```
How many students are there?
3
How many tests does each student have?
2
Enter the student's name:
Joohn
Enter the student's ID number:
1

Enter the test scores:
Score 1: 12

Score 2: 13

Enter the student's name:
Jack
Enter the student's ID number:
2

Enter the test scores:
Score 1: 67

Score 2: 45

Enter the student's name:
Jill
Enter the student's ID number:
3

Enter the test scores:
Score 1: 56

Score 2: 89


--------------------------------------------------------
Here is all the info I have for each student:
Student #1: 
Name: Joohn
ID Number: 1
Test Scores: Average Grade: 12
Letter Grade: F

Student #2: 
Name: Jack
ID Number: 2
Test Scores: Average Grade: 56
Letter Grade: F

Student #3: 
Name: Jill
ID Number: 3
Test Scores: Average Grade: 72
Letter Grade: C


--------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `inputScores` is declared like this

```
int *inputScores(int *studentList, int numTests, int count)
```

which means `studentList` is a pointer to an `int` (which can be treated like an array). Later in the function, you attempt to do this:

```
studentList[count].tests = new int[numTests];
```

If `studentList` is an `int*` (or `int` array), then `studentList[count]` is just an `int`. You're trying to access the member variable `tests` of an `int`. But `int` is a primitive type.

When you called this function in main, you correctly passed an `int*`:

```
studentList[i].tests = inputScores(studentList[i].tests, numTests, i);
```

So treating the variable like it were actually an `int *` instead of a `Grade *` should solve the first of your problems. You should also change the name of the variable, since you're not really passing a `studentList`, it's  more of a `tests` variable. That should help cut down on some of the confusion.

```
int *inputScores(int *tests, int numTests, int count)
```

After that, you'll realize that even through you're passing `studentList[i].tests` to your `inputScores` function, you'll have a memory leak and not be able to access the memory you thought you just filled. You DID fill memory, but when you tried to assign a new value to `tests` via `tests = new int[numTests];`, that only changed the local copy of `tests`.

To fix THAT problem, you need to pass `tests` by reference, like this:

```
int *inputScores(int*& tests, int numTests, int count)
```

That will allow any changes you make in your function to the `int*`, `tests`, to persist outside of the function.